# Unix open file from line X or first 100 lines after Z found

Tags: unix, grep, cat, hp-ux

I have a 2GB text file and I want to read every line 100 lines after a certain string is found
example:

```
string: 'epicvar (string) ="5"'
```

`string` was found on line 5000 so I want to read the file from 5000 to 5100
then the `string` was also found on line 15000 so I want to read the file from 15000 to 15100
and so on.

The system used is HP-UX B.11.31 U

Comment: Could you update tags indicating your OS? It looks like you are on Solaris or AIX

Comment: I would suggest compiling and installing [GNU grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) (perhaps with `./configure --prefix=$HOME/soft/` if you don't have root access) theu using the `grep -A100` as suggested in the deleted [answer by Fedorqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24799223/841108)

Comment: company server :D can't do those installs as I please ...unfortunatly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work for you (untested), if you understand `ll2p` means `last line to print`it should be easy enough to read...

```
awk '/pattern/ {ll2p = NR+100}
        NR < ll2p {print}
        NR==ll2p {ll2p=0} ' file
```

Comment: I tryed but it didn't output a thing ... maybe as something to do whit the "" in the pattern ??? 
awk '/epicvar (string) ="5"/ {ll2p = NR+100}
        NR < ll2p {print}
        NR==ll2p {ll2p=0} ' myfolder/myfile

Comment: Try just using `awk '/epicvar.*string.*5/...`